# Robocopy from source to particular directories

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, scripting

```
for /f "delims=," %%i in (input.txt) do (robocopy  "%%i" "%%j" /E /XF *.o *.lib)
```

pulls from the following folder input.txt, which is organized in csv format...

```
\\path\to\network\source\folder,C:\path\to\local\destination\source
...
```

Instead of copying the contents of each source into its respective folder, It is copying source to a "%j" folder one directory above source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below script to achieve your results. Just keep your file list in `input.txt` in `source,destination` (csv) format

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in (input.txt) do (robocopy  "%%i" "%%j" /E /XF *.o *.lib)
```

Cheers, G

Comment: Right now, when I run that command, It places the contents of the source into a "%%J" folder. My intention was to create a new folder corresponding to .txt. So two text files are beings used. One for the location of the contents being copied and one for a list of folders that will contain those contents.

Comment: can you update the question with your input file(source,destination) in csv format?

Comment: can you not simply have the input as `\\path\to\network\source,C:\path\to\local\destination\source` as thats by robocopy design. It copies the contents of the source folder to destination folder.

Comment: How does it know what to assign to %%j though? Would you not need to do something similar to %%i in (input.txt)

Comment: Hope you are aware of `tokens` in a for loop. refer `for /?` in cmd. If input.txt contains `\\path\to\network\source,C:\path\to\local\destination\source` it will assign `\\path\to\network\source` to `%%i` and `C:\path\to\local\destination\source` to `%%j`.

Comment: Gotcha. Still doesn't explain why command is creating a "%j" folder, and copying source contents to it. Have you checked to see if the command works on your end?

Comment: Can you try with the updated code now, I have added the tokens option which was missing earlier.